# Pointer in macro parameter list

Tags: c++, c, macros

I am currently attempting to define a function based on a compiler flag. If the TRACE flag is set, then I want to define a macro to pass information to a trace component.

```
#define TRACERPTR(Reporter * pReporter, traceComponent eComponent, traceLevel eLevel, string sFormat, formatArgs...) \
if (pReporter != NULL) { pReporter->trace(eComponent, eLevel, sFormat, ##formatArgs); }
```

Reporter is a class, defined in the same .h file, above this macro. I need to pass a pointer of a reporter object, which is then used to call the trace function.

However, I get a compiler error:

> error: "*" may not appear in macro
>   parameter list

I was curious as to what would occur if I just removed the "*" -- which results in the error "macro parameters must be comma-separated".

Any idea as to what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my knowledge, in C, at least, macro parameters aren't typed. It's all symbol substitution. Just use `pReporter` rather than `Reporter * pReporter` or `Reporter pReporter`.

(The same applies to the other parameters for your macro, I suppose.)

Answer (score 3):

As JAB pointed, macros are different than functions, they do not require the type of arguments

```
#define TRACERPTR(pReporter, eComponent, eLevel, sFormat, formatArgs...) \
if (pReporter != NULL) { pReporter->trace(eComponent, eLevel, sFormat, ##formatArgs); }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just place the `&` mark in your call:

```
#define SCAN_INT(str, myInt) (sscanf(str, "%d", myInt))

const char *myString = "23";
int myInteger;
SCAN_INT(myString, &myInteger);
```

Or you can automate it, like `ncurses`' `getyx()` does:

```
#define SCAN_INT(str, myInt) (sscanf(str, "%d", &myInt))

const char *myString = "23";
int myInteger;
SCAN_INT(myString, myInteger);
```

Hope it helps,
ief2